# Declaration vs Definition

Tags: c++

code:

```
  int main()
      {
        extern int a;
        int b;
        cout<<sizeof(a)<<endl;
        cout<<sizeof(b)<<endl;
      }
```

output:

```
4
4
```

If we just declare a variable, it shouldn't allocate memory for that variable(?).
So how would the compiler not giving an error for

```
 cout<<sizeof(a)<<endl;
```

or why the program is not getting crashed?

Comment: The type specifies the size of the object. When you do `int a;` it tells the compiler, "set aside 4 bytes of information for an incoming integer".

Comment: Also, `sizeof` doesn't evaluate its operand, so the behavior is defined.

Comment: `sizeof` works at compile time, not run time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sizeof` does not need to evaluate the expression that you pass to it, only its type. External definition `extern int a` is sufficient to figure out the type, so `sizeof` succeeds.

Moreover, since the expression inside `sizeof` does not get evaluated, the program links without an error.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` is resolved at compile time. All the compiler needs is a declaration with a complete type – it does *not* need to allocate storage for the object.

Since the `sizeof` expression is resolved at compile time, there’s consequently also *no way check* whether the object is actually defined in another compilation unit. If we *wanted* this check we couldn’t evaluate `sizeof` at compile time (we’d have to defer it to link time), and there’s simply no good reason for this delay.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler knows that `int` has a size of 4, and there's nothing that could ever give an `int` another size after compilation. Because of that, `sizeof(a)` becomes `sizeof(int)` which becomes `4`.

Answer (score 2):

sizeof() is not a function, it is a language keyword, that resolves to a compile time constant.

So - you are not accessing or using "a", rather you are asking the compiler a question about one of the pieces of information you provided it about "a".

```
cout << sizeof( a ) << endl:
```

is actually

```
cout << sizeof decltype(a) << endl;
```

is actually

```
cout << sizeof int << endl;
```

is actually

```
cout << 4 << endl;
```

You can verify this by looking at the assembly output. Under Linux, with GCC or Clang,

```
c++ -Wall -o test.S -S test.cpp
```

will generate the assembly file for you to inspect.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's getting the size of the type of the variable and not of the actual memory used (that should be the same).

```
int main () {
    int a = 2;

    std::cout << sizeof ((char) a) << std::endl; // Outputs 1

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `extern int a` you are just telling the compiler that there is (supposed to be) a variable named `a` of type `int` somewhere. However the only thing you do is to apply `sizeof` to it. Now the compiler doesn't need to access `a` to know its size: Since you told the compiler that `a` is of type `int`, it already knows its size: All `int`s are of the same size.

As of why the compiler does not give an error: A missing definition for an `extern` entity only gives an error if that entity is actually used. Since `sizeof` doesn't use it, but only tells you the size, you don't get a compiler error.